# How can I write $1^2+3^2+\dots+(2n+3)^2$ without using the dots?

Tags: notation

How can I write $1^2+3^2+\dots+(2n+3)^2$ without using the dots?

Please help me.

Comment: Well, that you've generalize that $(2n+3)^2$ is a term should be a *huge* hint.  $1^2 = (2*(-1) + 3)^2$ and $3=(2*0 + 3)^2$ and the next term is $5^2 = (2*1 + 3)^2$.  So this is $\sum\limits_{k=-1}^n(2n+3)^2$.

Comment: It's unclear whether you are asking about notation (which is how I read it, thus my tag edit) or about finding a closed-form formula for the series (which would imply that "summation" would be a good tag). This confusion is reflected in the different answers you have been given.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(2k+1)^2.
$$Do you know the symbol $\sum$?

Comment: Why not $2n+3$?

Comment: @user557276 $2n+3$ is obtained as $2(n+1)+1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (2k+1)^2 = 1^2+3^2+\dots+(2n+3)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$1^2+3^2+\dots+(2n+3)^2=  (1^2+2^2+\dots+(2n+3)^2)-4(1^2+2^2+\dots+(n+1)^2)$$
$$= {(2n+3)(2n+4)(4n+7)\over 6}-4{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)\over 6}$$
$$= 2(n+2)(2n+3){4n+7-2n-2\over 6}$$
$$= (n+2)(2n+3){2n+15\over 3}$$
It is without dots :).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
1^2+3^2+\dots+(2n+3)^2
&=1^2+2^2+3^2+\dots+(2n+2)^2+(2n+3)^2+(2n+4)^2\\
&\qquad-4(1^2+2^2+\dots+(n+2)^2)\\[6px]
&=\frac{1}{3}(2n+4)\left(2n+4+\frac{1}{2}\right)(2n+4+1)\\
&\qquad-4\cdot\frac{1}{3}(n+2)\left(n+2+\frac{1}{2}\right)(n+2+1)\\[6px]
&=\frac{2}{3}(n+2)\left(\left(2n+\frac{9}{2}\right)(2n+5)-2\left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right)(n+3)\right)\\[6px]
&=\frac{1}{3}(n+2)(2n+5)(4n+9-2(n+3))\\[6px]
&=\frac{1}{3}(n+2)(2n+3)(2n+5)
\end{align}